# Pushing pointer with registry value into stack

Tags: pointers, assembly, nasm

I am new to assembly, I am trying to push a pointer, modified by a value from a registry eg:

```
Push Pointer+edx
```

where edx is initialized to 1.

```
Push Pointer + 1
```

works for me, but that fail the learning purpose.

I am using NASM

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that directly. You can instead do:

```
push Pointer
add [esp], edx
```

To add the offset to the already pushed value.
If you don't care about `edx` you can also do:

```
add edx, Pointer
push edx
```

Or you can also use a different register of course.